# How to create datePicker And timePicker with customization

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, datetimepicker

I want to create a `DatePicker` like one below And `TimePicker` , but this will pop up from bottom .

[image]

Comment: Use Fragment, and animate it from bottom to the top.

Comment: mmm okay ,, i'm always using `datepicker Dialog` how can i implemented on fragment ?

Comment: Use DatePicker widget view in xml and perform all the actions in Fragment. link: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/